# How to change video in vlcj-4

Tags: java, swing, video, awt, vlcj

i'm trying to change the video thats being played by vlcj. But when it's supposed to switch video, the application just closes. It does not throw any errors, it just exits. This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;

public class Main {

    private final JFrame frame;

    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
    public Main() {
        frame = new JFrame("My First Media Player");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                mediaPlayerComponent.release();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        frame.add(mediaPlayerComponent);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().submit(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().play("E:\\Somevideo1.mkv");
            }
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        }


        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().submit(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Reached 1");
                mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().play("E:\\Somevideo2.mkv");
                System.out.println("Reached 2");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

It prints "Reached 1" but the application exits before it reaches "Reached 2".

EDIT: So it seems it's an filetype issue, it only crashes when the previous video was a .mkv video. When changing from mp4 to mkv it works just fine, but when changing from mkv to another mkv or a mp4 it crashes.

EDIT 2: I tried switching from vsc to IntelliJ and now i get the error message: "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

On the internet i was able to find this: https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.vc.debugger/c/_n9juoV-5m8?pli=1

"What you see is typical to the foloowng scenario:

1. A thread exhausts its stack space; EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW
   exception (0xC00000FD) is risen.
2. A thread swallows EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW and continue
   execution.
3. At the next attempt to grow stack, the system takes control,
   issues EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xC0000005) exception and
   terminates the process immediately - without any GUI message!

Now, this scenario is true to all WinNT line from 4.0 up to XP.
However, I read it somewhere that now Vista and higher shows some
error message to the user. The process is terminated on the spot,
anyway. "

But it doesn't change the fact that it does not work. I also got the opportunity to try it on multiple PC's and the same error happens, so it's not an PC related issue.

EDIT 3: I tried making a C# WPF app using the libVLCSharp official binding and i get the exact same error.

EDIT 4: I tried using --verbose=2 but nothing prints when it is supposed to change, only the same: "The program '[12156] VLCSharpTest.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'." Error

Comment: Looks like you have an invalid path `"E\\Somevideo2.mkv"`, add a colon `:` after `E`

Comment: Regardless of the missing colon, the application should not just be terminating if that filename is wrong, and it doesn't just terminate for me if I run your code.

Comment: You don't need those submit calls with the Runnables here. Just inline the code. It won't solve your posted issue though.

Comment: What happens if you put your two mkv files into a playlist in the VLC application and play that?

Comment: @caprica The same thing happens when i put it in a playlist. But i tried using the libVLCsharp library in a C# WPF application and i get the exact same error. I honestly have no idea why it's happening at this point.

Comment: Does it happen with every mkv you try? From what you've posted here, I can only suggest there's something wrong with that particular mkv file, or your mkv file is triggering a bug in VLC itself. Your problem seems unrelated to LibVLC or any language bindings. Maybe post an issue at the VideoLAN GitLab.